# Can the product of $31256$ and $8427$ be $263395312$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here is a question that I saw recently:

> Can the product of $31256$ and $8427$ be $263395312$ ?

I am absolutely clueless on how to approach the problem. The only thing I checked was if the units digit of the actual product and the given match and they do. I am not sure what to do next. What are the concepts/tricks being used here? 
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hint: think divisibility rules

Comment: Count factors of $2$.  Though, actually, just multiplying the two numbers is only slightly slower.

Comment: Is $8427$ a multiple of three?  How can you tell?  Is $31256\times 8427$ a multiple of three then?  Is $263395312$ a multiple of three?

Comment: As an aside, the actual result of the multiplication happens to be $26339\color{red}{4}312$ so logarithm arguments or divisibility arguments for $1000$ or factors of $1000$ will fail.  That said, divisibility arguments for numbers coprime to $1000$ should work.  The most recognizable is often that for $3$, but $7$ or $11$ and so on should have worked as well.  $31256\mapsto 3-1+2-5+6=5$ and $8427\mapsto -8+4-2+7=1$ so $31256\times 8427$ should be $5$ more than a multiple of $11$ however $263395312\mapsto 2-6+3-3+9-5+3-1+2=4$ is only four more than a multiple of $11$, not five.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $8247$ is a multiple of $3$ but $263395312$ is not a multiple of $3$.

A quick way to check this is to sum their digits and check if that's divisible by $3$.